# How to jump/hide first index ? with flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a streambuilder with ListView who display a list of data by date but I try to not show the current date or the first index from the list. So I don't found how to jump to never show this index

```
 StreamBuilder<List<Todo4>>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('$current_id:vote_stories')
                  .orderBy("date", descending: true)
                  .snapshots()
                  .transform(Utils.transformer(Todo4.fromJson)),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  default:
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return buildText('Something Went Wrong Try later');
                    } else {
                      final todos4 = snapshot.data;
                      final provider = Provider.of<TodosProvider>(context);
                      provider.setTodos4(todos4);
                      return    SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                          child:


                          todos4.isEmpty
                              ? Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Pas de suite',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          )
                              :
                          ListView.separated(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),

                            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            scrollDirection:  Axis.vertical,
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(width: 8,height:8),
                          itemCount: todos4.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                              final todo4 = todos4[index];

                              return ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                  child:  GestureDetector(
                                    child:  Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,

                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            "${todo4.suite}",
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, height: 1.5),
                                          ),


                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                              );
                            }

                          )

                      );
                    }
                }
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something simple like these might do the trick inside the `ListView`

```dart
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        if(index==0)return SizedBox.shrink();
                              final todo4 = todos4[index];
```